# How do I choose one particular blog post out of multiple in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I have a `models.py` structure similar to this

```
class Entertainmentblog(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    img_url0 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img_alt0 =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now if I have to take one of the blog posts and display it as a image masthead on the top of the page.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perform your query and then index it, probably using the 0th index. This will add a `LIMIT` clause to the underlying query.

Comment: If OP is using Django 1.6+ then the `.first()`/ `.last()` method is also available on all QuerySets.